# iMacros Proxy Authentication - Not able to write login credentials

Tags: javascript, proxy, automation, eval, imacros

I am not able to authenticate proxy address using iMacros.
The ONLOGIN doesn't work out.
Messed around it as well.
I need it to work.
If any other workaround, like using javascript or some EVAL command.

Look forward to answers, 
I am using Firefox browser version 51, iMacros addon Version - 8.9.7

Comment: Perhaps you should simply record filling in credentials with some recording mode.

Comment: It's not working you can't record the pop-up